# Where are external /jar files on Hadoop stored?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

Lets say I write a WordCount example, and then in the eclipse project include an external jar file such as MyJar.jar. Now if I export the whole WordCount project as a word.jar file, and then type

```
$> hadoop jar word.jar WordCount input output
```

I understand that the job executes and the word.jar will have a lib directory that contains MyJar.jar file. Now, where on the HDFS will this jar file MyJar file be stored when the job is running that makes calls to methods of this jar file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bin/hadoop script actually unpacks your work.jar file into a tmp folder on the local file system.

The Job client handles the creation of a job folder in HDFS where your original jar, all the lib jars and other job files (such as the job.xml, distributed cache files etc) are uploaded to.

When your job runs on a cluster node, these files are copied back down to a tmp job directory on the local file system of that node. For efficiency reasons the files are only copied down once, rather than for each map tasks which runs on that node.

Comment: That makes sense. But, how do you explain this: The client copies the resources needed to run the job, including the job JAR file, the configuration
file, and the computed input splits, to the jobtracker’s filesystem in a
directory named after the job ID. The job JAR is copied with a high replication
factor (controlled by the mapred.submit.replication property, which defaults to
10).
This paragraph doesn't make so much sense. Firstly, because it says the that the client copies evrything to the fs of the jobtracker and then that the job jar is highly replicated.

Comment: By job trackers fs, they mean HDFS